# How to export a nova resource to excel WITHOUT actions?

Tags: laravel-nova, laravel-excel

I am using Nova and Laravel-Nova-Excel.

I need to export the contents of a nova-resource (+ add any filters) by cron on disk, as Excel. How to do it right?

Now I see this option:

1. Get the query builder from the resource (how to do it? - the main problem)
2. Create a query class as described here - https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-query.html
3. Export the file.

Does anyone know other options?

Answer (score 0):

You would like to export all the models connected to a certain nova-resource to excel from a cron job. Please correct me if I misinterpreted your question.

`Laravel-Nova-Excel` package is a nova wrapper around [Laravel Excel](https://docs.laravel-excel.com). It will be easier to just use the package directly instead of the nova wrapper.

- Use this guide [Laravel Excel - quick start](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/) to define a Excel `ExportModel` class in which you define your filter logic.
- Create a [Laravel Command](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#writing-commands) in which you trigger the `ExportModel` class. The following artisan command can be used to generate a laravel command : `php artisan make:command ExportModel`

  - Use this command in your existing cronjob: `php artisan command:export`
  - Or use the built in laravel schedules [laravel schedules](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#main-content)